# Loop through an array MIPS Assembly

Tags: c, arrays, assembly, while-loop, mips

I'm working on a program which loops through an array of 10 numbers. The first 9 elements have values higher than 0, the 10th has a value of 0. The loop should break when the 0 is encountered.

```
i=0;
while(A[i]!=0)
{
    A[i]=A[i]+1;
    i++;
}
```

I know I can use 'beq' to break the loop if the value of the register is equal to 0. However I don't know enough about manipulating values in the memory.

It's my first time using MIPS and you'll see it's a mess. If you can't fix it for me, can you give me some pointers?

```
.data  #by default, the "data segment" starts at address 0x10010000
.word 1
.word 2
.word 3
.word 4
.word 5
.word 6
.word 7
.word 8
.word 9
.word 0

.text #instructions start below

# MIPS assembly code

lui  $a0, 0x1001           # $a0 = 0x10010000
addi $a1, $zero, 0         # i = 0
jal increment              # call the procedure
```

Here's where I'm most lost:

```
increment:
lui $a0, 0x1001           # $a0 = 0x10010000
beq $a0, $zero, else      # if $a0 holds 0 goto 'else'
addi $a0, $a0, 2          # +2
addi $a1, $zero, 1        # i = i + 1

jr $ra                   #jump to caller
```

$v0 should hold the sum of all the incremented values.

```
else: 
add $a0, $v0, $zero #copy result as input to syscall
addi $v0,$zero,1 #service 1 for syscall is print integer
syscall
```

Finishes with an infinite loop.

```
infinite: j infinite
```

Comment: You say $v0 should hold the sum of all incremented values, but this is not what the C code does.  It increments all the values in the array by 1.  Which do you want?

Comment: Both of them really, the loop to increment the values by 1, and $v0 to store the sum of all the incremented values. So if it will work maybe I can add the new value to $v0 in the loop after adding 1 to it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To load a value from a memory, you need to call one of the load instructions, (`lw`, `lh` or `lb` for word, half-word and byte). for example:

```
lw $a1, 0($a2) # load a word from the address in $a2 + offset 0 to $a1
```

to write a value in memory, you use one of the store commands, for example:

```
sw $a1, 0($a2) # store the word in $a1 into the address in $a2 + offset
```

loading an address into a register is done using la, for example

```
la $a2, label_of_array # load the address of the label 'label_of_array' into $a2
```

Now, to manipulate the value in the array, you need to combine the three instructions from above:

```
la $a1, label_of_array   # load the address of the array into $a1
lb $a2, 0($a1)           # load a byte from the array into $a2
addi $a2, $a2, 1         # increment $a2 by 1
sb $a2, 0($a1)           # store the new value into memory
addi $a1, $a1, 1         # increment $a1 by one, to point to the next element in the array
```

And another point:

You wrote `addi $a1, $zero, 1        # i = i + 1` but this is wrong. What you did is to store the result of `$zero + 1` which is `1` into `$a1`. In order to increment `$a1`, you need to write `addi $a1, $a1, 1` which is "store the result of `$a1 + 1` into `$a1`.

Comment: Thanks that's helpful. But how can I increase the offset with each loop of the array, or effectively use the index? Edit: Don't worry, I see it.

Comment: Don't increase the offset, increase the register that holds the address of the array (as in the last line of the code sample I posted)

Comment: Yes, just noticed it. Thanks.